# node_modules disappears from my directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, backend

**When I entered npm install in VS Code terminal.**

```
   PS D:\work\backEnd> npm install
   npm WARN old lockfile
   npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
   npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
   npm WARN old lockfile
   npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...<br/>
   npm WARN old lockfile
   [##################] / reify:fsevents: sill reify mark deleted ['D:\\work\\backEnd\\node_modules\\fsevents' ]
```

The folder *node_modules* will be installed in the directory.
But after some time, maybe like say 1 or 2 mins. the folder `node_modules` has vanished.

This is shown in the terminal.

````
   npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
   npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
   npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
   npm ERR! request to 
   https://eu.artifactory.conti.de/artifactory/api/npm/i_cvam_rvd_npm_v/yn/-/yn-3.1.1.tgz failed, 
   reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN eu.artifactory.conti.de

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     C:\Users\vaibhav\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-21T17_27_31_359Z-debug-0.log
   PS D:\work\backEnd>```
````

I am new to nodejs. can someone help me, please?

Comment: Seems like one library can't be installed properly, specifically this one: `https://eu.artifactory.conti.de/artifactory/api/npm/i_cvam_rvd_npm_v/yn/-/yn-3.1.1.tgz`. Double check if the path is correct and if you are logged in and have access to donwload from that NPM server.

Answer (score 1):

`eu.artifactory.conti.de` can't be resolved. There is no DNS entry for that address.

Usually packages are installed from the NPM repository, but this one seems to be installed from a custom URL. You should be able to see it listed in the `package.json` file.

Because `npm` isn't able to install the package, it rolls back the `install` action, which removes the `node_modules` directory.

Contact the author of the project you're trying to install to see if that package is available elsewhere.